# JQuery apply loop for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a chart with four level hierarchy. I had to find the parent element and apply a class. Currently i am able to find a single element and apply the class. 
Can someone tell me how to loop through all the classes and append a Class.

Here is the part of code

```
dataBound: function() {

  var treeview = $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView');

  if ($('.firstlevel').parent().parent().siblings() !== undefined) {
    $.each($('.firstlevel').parent().parent().siblings(), function() {
      if ($(this).find('.secondlevel').length == 1) {
        $(this).find('li').addClass('sole');
      }
    });
  }
  if ($(".thirdlevel").parent().parent().siblings() !== undefined) {
    $.each($(".thirdlevel").parent().parent().siblings(), function() {
      if ($(this).find(".fourthlevel").length == 1) {
        debugger
        $(this).find("li").addClass("sole");
      }
    });
  }
},
```

```html
<ul class="k-group" role="group" style="display: block;">
  <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last sole" data-uid="18cc5c0c-cd30-44a4-88ef-3cbf49cd2b60" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" data-expanded="true" id="treeview_tv_active">
    <div class="k-bot">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-collapse">
</span>
      <span class="k-in">
    <div class="secondlevel">Building 1</div>
</span></div>
    <ul class="k-group" role="group" style="display: block;">
      <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last sole" data-uid="2e89f300-c08f-4e34-96ca-402bf773a95d" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" data-expanded="true">
        <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-i-collapse"></span><span class="k-in">

    <div class="thirdlevel">Department 1</div>

</span></div>
        <ul class="k-group" role="group" style="display: block;">
          <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last sole" data-uid="d67ba082-84ef-4e04-a447-4011c0935e10" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" data-expanded="true">
            <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">
    <div class="fourthlevel">Line 1</div>
</span></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share sample markup

Comment: Show us the hierarchy

Comment: I still do not see the hierarchy

Comment: Yup. Updated Latest with full hierarchy

Comment: I am getting the desired output, but i need to run two loops which is time consuming, Is there any way i can write this in a single loop ?

Comment: An extra suggestion, Why don't you write a single function and pass classes. That will make your code simple and re-usable for other classes as well.

Comment: @Shahzeb , Yup i tried for the same, but i am not getting the output, probably i must have made some error. Can you please show me how to ?

Comment: @tkamath99 On my answer you suggested it was not working. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Rajesh - Yes, The class is not getting appended, so basically i am using a kendo ui framework, where there is a method for creating a treeview structure, Upon executing the code you provided, the class is not getting added for the last element in the li. It is also throwing an error as Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: *Maximum call stack size exceeded* happens when you use recursion. Code I suggested was straight forward. Still my suggestion would be to use complex selectors to avoid loops like `$(".fourthlevel:first-child li", $('.thirdlevel').parents('div')).addClass('sole')`